# Creating a class in PHP first time OO

Tags: php

Ok, this is a really, really newbie question, but I've googled and tried several different way of doing this with no luck. My first time making a class in PHP. I'm making a simple class that will query an e-mail to a DataBase and it will return if the e-mail exists in that database or not. Here is how I made the class.

```
<?php
class isEmailUnique{
    private $email;
    include '../dbc/DBC.php';
    $collection = $db->members;
    $ifEmailRaw = $collection->find(array('eMail' => $email));
    $ifEmail = $ifEmailRaw  -> count();
    if($ifEmail > 0){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }   
}
?>
```

Here is how I am using the class:

```
<?php

include 'classes/checkEmailIsUnique.php';

echo isEmailUnique->'text@test.com';

?>
```

Here is my error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/partycloud.tv/public_html/php/test.php on line 5
```

My desired result would that it returns either 1 or 0.

I know this is probably very easy, I just don't get it how to construct a class, I'm having a very difficult time comprehending the few articles I've read. Any help with this would be awesome! Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Have you followed a tutorial? It looks as if you're just guessing. Read http://php.net/oop

Comment: What you have there are several statements stuck into the class definition in no particular context. Except of `private $email;`, everything else there belongs inside some assortment of class methods.  But exactly where depends what you're attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how classes work. Here's an example of what an OOP version of your code *could* look like:

```
<?php
    class EmailHelper {
        private $db;

        public function __construct() {
            include '../dbc/DBC.php';
            $this->db = new DBC();
        }

        public function IsUnique($email) {
            $collection = $this->db->members;
            $ifEmailRaw = $collection->find(array('eMail' => $email));
            $ifEmail = $ifEmailRaw->count();

            return ($ifEmail <= 0);
        }

        public function IsValid($email) {
            /* Logic */
        }

        public function IsFromDomain($email, $domain) {
            /* Logic */
        }
    }

    $emailHelper = new EmailHelper();
    if ($emailHelper->IsUnique('text@test.com')) {
        echo 'Unique!';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Here's what i'd like to understand, where does the variable '$db' come from? and why is there always this function '__construct()'? Thank you so much for answering btw!

Comment: @user2287474 `__construct` gets called as soon as you use `new Class();`. Then it sets `$this->db` (refering to `private $db`) to `new DBC()` (or however you create your database object), and when you want to refer to the `$db` variable, you use `$this->db` as we saved it.

Comment: See this is what no one ever explains to you. Makes complete sense. I really needed just that little bit of explanation. Thank you so much! Stack overflow won't let me accept the answer for another 5 minutes, I'll see you in 5!

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is kind of an (illegal) hybrid of a class and a function.  Look up how to define a member function within a class.  As a hint, the line that is erroring is going to have to look more something like this, well, as your class is now defined:

echo isEmailUnique->check('text@test.com');

...where check() is the member function you define.  Probably you mean something more like this:

echo whateverYourClassNameIs->isEmailUnique('text@test.com');

...where your current class name is really meant to be a function name within the class...

Comment: Yeah that's where I was having trouble. usually I'll just use a function, But because I want to encapsulate certain things like `include '../dbc/DBC.php';` I needed to use a class, I just never understood how to actually use one in PHP. Thank you for your reply!